# Help with unity cel shader not work when turning away from the main light?

Tags: unity, shaders, lighting, cel-shading

So i'm using this really good [toon](https://pastebin.com/8uqxht3y) shader I found, that works with multiple directional and point lights. Only problem is, it acts weirdly when turning away from the main light seen [here](https://streamable.com/au373r), ( sorry for the video in the backround). I would like it be be more realistic, like in real life where light bounces off multiple objects. As of now, if it's in shadow in acts as if no light is hitting it. Would appreciate any help, and apologize if this issue is stupid, i'm still learning shaders.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you want this to look like instead. If you want bounce lighting, that's termed "global illumination" and it's not present in the shader you're using. It also requires specialized scene setup to apply to dynamic objects, like placing lighting probes. I'm not sure if I've ever seen global illumination implemented in a cell shaded game, though some fake it for select areas using hand-placed point lights.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, basically I want it to get indirect lighting whenever I turn away from the directional light his skin goes completely dark, and ignores the ambient light that effects other objects. You seem really knowledgeable, do you have any advice on how to get indirect lighting? Or is it just impossible with a toon shader? I was reading that it's somehow accomplished in BOTW here: https://www.resetera.com/threads/zelda-breath-of-the-wild-the-technical-analysis.8197/. Btw thank you very much for responding.

Comment: Sounds like they're rendering a light probe at Link's location, and adding its contribution as a directional ambient on all materials in the scene.

Comment: Oh that actually makes more sense thank you. So if this shader I have is a surface, and therfore supports ambient lights such as point lights, do you think it would be able to be affected by light probes somehow?

Comment: If you want to mimic the exact BOTW style, I'd suggest adding that in by hand. Probably as an emissive channel in your surface function.

Comment: Ya I guess you're right, I'll just have to add in a lot of ambient lights. Thank you for all the advice.